# I have two action links and a single model popup window. is there any way to know which action link was clicked

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

```html
<div><a data-toggle="modal" href="#accmodel" data-target="#accmodel" id="addacc">AddAccomodation</a>
    <div id=modeldetails1></div>
</div>
<div><a data-toggle="modal" href="#accmodel" data-target="#accmodel" id="addacc2">AddAccomodation</a>
    <div id=modeldetails2></div>
</div>
```

> on click of the submit button in the model popup i need to find out which action link triggered the popup so that i could append the details to coressponding div

```html
<div>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#accmodel" data-target="#accmodel" id="addacc2">AddAccomodation</a>
    <div id=modeldetails2></div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="accmodel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body col-sm-12" id="mbody">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="acctext" class="accomodation"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="saveaccbtn">Add</button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by this simple way

```js
    $("#addacc").on("click", function(){
        // append the details to the corresponding div for this button as you want
        $("#accmodel").find("#mbody").text("Any contant for first button was clicked accordingly");
    });

    $("#addacc2").on("click", function(){
        // append the details to the corresponding div for this button as you want
        $("#accmodel").find("#mbody").text("Any contant for second button was clicked accordingly");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div><a data-toggle="modal" href="#accmodel" data-target="#accmodel" id="addacc">AddAccomodation</a>
<div id=modeldetails1></div></div>
<div><a data-toggle="modal" href="#accmodel" data-target="#accmodel" id="addacc2">AddAccomodation</a>
<div id=modeldetails2></div></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="accmodel" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">     
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body col-sm-12" id="mbody">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="acctext" class="accomodation"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"id="saveaccbtn">Add</button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @vishag v.j

Answer (score 3):

you can do this using jquery simply

```
<div><a  href="#accmodel" data-clicked="from link 1" id="addacc">AddAccomodation</a>
<div id="modeldetails1"></div></div>
<div><a href="#accmodel" data-clicked="from link 2"   id="addacc2">AddAccomodation</a>
 <div id="modeldetails2"></div></div>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){


   $('#addacc').click(function(){
      alert($(this).data('clicked'));
      $('#accmodel').modal('show');
   });

  $('#addacc2').click(function(){
     alert($(this).data('clicked'));
     $('#accmodel').modal('show');
  });
 });
 </script>
```